# One-To-One Eloquent Relationship functions

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

There is something I miss in the eloquent one-to-one relationship:

```
class MeetingTest extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'meeting_tests';

    public function meeting() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Meeting','meeting_id','id');
    }

    public function observation() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Observation','meeting_test_id','id');
    }

    public function activity() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\TestActivity','activity_id','id');
    }
}
```

The Observation Class is

```
class Observation extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'observations';

    public function meetingTest() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\MeetingTest','meeting_test_id','id');
    }
}
```

If I run php artisan tinker and

```
$mtn = App\MeetingTest::create();
$mtn->save();

$ob = App\Observation::create();
$ob->save;

$mtn->observation()->save($ob);
```

At this point inside the Observation record I can see the meeting_test_id filled with the correct id of the meetingTest, but if I try:

$mtn->observation

it gives me null; and in the Database there is no observation ID in the observation_id field;

this is the migration:

```
Schema::create('meeting_tests', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('meeting_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('observation_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->integer('activity_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

I don't understand what is not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see **observation_id** and **activity_id** in your **meeting_tests** table, which makes records in this table the **owned** side of one-to-one/one-to-many relation. Therefore, both **activity** and **observation** relations in **MeetingTest** should return **$this->belongsTo** instead of **$this->hasOne**